# Google Account collecting browser history and cookies?

Tags: anonymity, google

I am using some random site in Microsoft Edge. There are no account associate neither with the site nor the browser. Now,

1. What will happen if I login in Google Account and keep it logged in. Will it collect my browsing history and cookies?
2. What will happen if I logged out after successful login in Google Account. Will it be able to collect my browsing history and cookies, or something else?

Comment: Are you logging into a web page using your Google account or does Microsoft Edge support logging in via Google account (for user management)

Comment: logging into a web page using your Google account SSO. such as, gmail or other google acc.

Answer (score 4):

Browsers generally implement a level of isolation between the websites and the browser. So a website may not be able to directly fetch the browser history or cookies created by other sites. Services like Google, Facebook, Twitter etc are ubiquitous due to ads, like buttons etc.

It is possible for these services to fetch your browsing history by indirect ways. They won't be able to get all the cookies on your browser though as the cookies are bound to the url that created them.

> What will happen if I login in Google Account and keep it logged in. Will it collect my browsing history and cookies?

Browsing history via browser? No. Google ads can create cookies saying you connected to this website that uses Google ad. This data can then be used by Google to build your browsing history

> What will happen if I logged out after successful login in Google
>   Account. Will it be able to collect my browsing history and cookies,
>   or something else?

Logging out temporarily stops the Google service from being able to link the browsing to your account. When you log back in, Google can look at the cookies that it stored to get an idea about the browsing history on that macine and possibly link it to you. Of course, it won't always be able to link that browsing history specifically to you. For example, if you are sharing a browser with multiple people, Google may not know who was particularly browsing the computer if nobody is logged in.

Comment: Google and others can track you too if you are not logged in. While they can not immediately associate the data with a Google account if you never logged in they can still associate the browsing with the same browser and therefore user (unless multiple users use the same browser) and then associate these collected information with an account once you log in.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich umm I thought my last paragraph said that. If it wasn't clear, I can reword it

Comment: It wasn't clear for me from *"...can look at the cookies to get an idea about the history"* that you've meant the same as I said, i.e. that it still tracks  even if nobody is logged in and that it can later associate the collected data with a specific user once one is logged in. Maybe you could expand your description to make it more clear that being logged off does not really help.